# What causes cold start in serverless

Tags: kubernetes, azure-functions, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have read enough papers on serverless cold start, but have not found a clear explanation on what causes cold start. Could you try to explain it from both commercial and open-source platform's points of view?

1. commercial platform such as AWS Lambda or Azure Funtion. I know they are more like a black-box to us
2. There are open-source platforms such as OpenFaaS, Knative, or OpenWhisk. Do those platforms also have a cold start issue?

My initial understanding about cold start latency is time spent on spinning up a container. After the container being up, it can be reused if not being killed yet, so there is a warm start. Is this understanding really true? I have tried to run a container locally from the image, no matter how large the image is, the latency is near to none.

Is the image download time also part of cold start? But no matter how many cold starts happened in one node, only one image download is needed, so this seems to make no sense.

Maybe a different question, I also wonder what happened when we instantiate a container from the image? Are the executable and its dependent libraries (e.g., Python library) copied from disk into memory during this stage? What if there are multiple containers based on the same image? I guess there should be multiple copies from disk to memory because each container is an independent process.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/

Comment: @VovaBilyachat Thank you. This still looks similar to the process of pulling an image and instantiating a container. But I still feel that instantiating a container does not need much time. At least from my experience with `docker run` I heard Lambda and Azure can waste seconds on cold start. I know a real serverless application is way complicated than a local container, so I may just let it go.

Comment: I will type my answer after i get back home

Comment: @VovaBilyachat Hi Vova, not sure if still can see and comment on this question. Sorry but my post has been closed by someone. Should I ask on DevOps Beta Stack Exchange? since comment has a limit on the number of words.

Comment: Yes you can but I think its closed because this huge topic.

Comment: @VovaBilyachat Could you please answer from this session [question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13934/what-causes-cold-start-in-serverless)

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of levels of "cold start" that all add latency. The hottest of the hot paths is the container is still running and additional requests can be routed to it. The coldest is a brand new node so it has to pull the image, start the container, register with SD, wait for the serverless plane's routing stuffs to update, probably some more steps if you dig deep enough. Some of those can happen in parallel but most can't. If the pod has been shut down because it wasn't being used, and the next run schedules on the same machine then yes kubelet usually skips pulling image (unless imagePullPolicy Always is forced somewhere) so you get a bit of a faster launch. K8s' scheduler doesn't generally optimize for that though.

Comment: Thank you! (1) I was wondering what is register with SD (2) You mean k8s scheduler normally will not schedule the new request onto the alive pod? it has no affinity to a node even though this node has the image stored. But Then how can a warm start happened if scheduler has no affinity.

Comment: The k8s scheduler is not related to requests, it handles placing new pods on nodes. It does not optimize for "the image is already on disk" as part of that process. Request routing is up to your particular serverless framework, somewhere each of them will have an HTTP service of some kind, or configure an existing one, which processes incoming requests, figures out which code the correspond to, and sending things on their way. This is the SD system as well in most cases (SD == service discovery), or at least builds on the one included in K8s (Services).

Comment: I am not familiar with the relation between k8s and serverless frameworks. Could you provide me some material to read, or maybe I should get hands dirty to understand. For `openfaas` it looks like the serverless framework is the front-end that responds to the request, i.e., running serverless on a k8s cluster. But for framework such as `openwhisk` I know how its architecture looks like. I am really confused about how could it combine with a k8s cluster.

Comment: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/knative/

Comment: Explaining the architecture of every serverless tool is well out of scope for a SO comment, sorry.

Comment: @coderanger Hi, can i say that while k8s has no affinity on the node that has an image stored or has a living container running, but the serverless framework can decide this to reduce cold strat occurrence? In other words, serverless framework enhances the functionality of k8s. I asked the question on a stack exchange community, would you please have a look [link](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13921/what-is-the-relation-between-serverless-and-kubernetes)